# HTML5 Dragging and Dropping multiple elements between multiple browser windows

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I made the HTML5 drag and drop working fine for single element. This is working good across the multiple browsers too e.g. i have two same or different browser windows open and i can drag from one browser and drop the element into the dropzone of another browser - this works fine for single element.

Has anyone idea how to make this work if want to select multiple elements and drag drop ?

Answer (score 6):

You cannot drag more than one thing at a time, what you would need to do is something along these lines.  In this example suppose we have a multi select list, when you drag one selected element, all selected elements should be dragged.

1. Listen for a dragstart event on one of the draggables
2. When setting the dataTransfer - you need to encode data in there that will represent all the stuff you want dragged.
3. Customise the drag image to show the user more than one thing is being dragged.

See example here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stevendwood/pAmhQ/1/)

```
$(".draggableThingsSelector").on("dragstart", function(e) {
   e = e.originalEvent;

   var fruitList = [],
       dragImage = document.createElement("ul");

   $("li.selected").each(function() {
       fruitList.push(this.innerHTML);
       dragImage.appendChild(this.cloneNode(true));
   });

   e.dataTransfer.setData("fruits", JSON.stringify(fruitList));
});
```

Also see here for more discussion of drag image support :[drag image support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766103/html5-drag-and-drop-events-and-setdragimage-browser-support/20585673#20585673)

Comment: Fiddle seems to be broken

Comment: It wont work on IE.  However if you're not using IE make sure you click on a fruit to select it before you start dragging it.

Comment: Using Chrome. Click-to-select solved it. There is the issue with the momentary flash when the ul is being composed, though I'd guess you could solve that by rendering it off-screen.