# HTML5 Drag-Drop: SetDragImage not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drag-and-drop

I'm new to front-end programming and experimenting with HTML5 drag-drop. The object to drag is a bootstrap `div.panel` which does its job pretty well. However, whilst the object is being dragged, I want to show a custom image using `SetDragImage` function. I've used this function precisely as described in the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer#setDragImage.28.29), but still its not working - the default blank rectangle is shown when the object is dragged.

Below is the JavaScript for the drag/drop events, and here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/93jq19c1/1/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drag(ev){
    //var style = window.getComputedStyle(ev.target, null);
    var ss  = (parseInt($(ev.target).position().left,10) - ev.clientX) + ',' + (parseInt($(ev.target).position().top,10) - ev.clientY);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ss);

    ev.dataTransfer.setDragImage(document.getElementById("draggit"), 0, 0);
    console.log("drag:target", $(ev.target).position().left + "," + $(ev.target).position().top);
    console.log("drag:offset", ss);
}

function drop(ev) {
    //console.log("drop:" +  $(ev.target).position().left + ","  + $(ev.target).position().top);
    //console.log("drop:" +  ev.clientX + ","  + ev.clientY);
    var offset = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    var npos = offset.split(",");
    console.log("drop_clientpos:" +  ev.clientX + "," + ev.clientY);
    console.log("drop_newpos:" +  (ev.clientX + parseInt(npos[0])) + "," + (ev.clientY + parseInt(npos[1])));
    document.getElementById("dragme").style.left = (ev.clientX + parseInt(npos[0])) + "px";
    document.getElementById("dragme").style.top = (ev.clientY + parseInt(npos[1])) + "px";

    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function dragOver(ev) {

    ev.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You should add javascript to your tags, you will get a better answer quicker.

Comment: Thanks, `javascript` just skipped my mind. I've added it now.

Comment: double up question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766103/html5-drag-and-drop-events-and-setdragimage-browser-support