# Drag & drop set custom HTML as drag image

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to somehow set my custom html object to `event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(myCustomHtml,0,0)` ?

I tried like this

```
var x=$doc.getElementById("row_selected_notification");
event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(x, 100, 100);
```

but it didn't work.

As I'm doing this through Java, I'm using native methods so jQuery is not an option for me.

Answer (score 35):

You can either create a custom element on drag or use an existing element.
If you are crating an element you have to make sure it is not visible after adding it to the DOM. I've just added a negative top value to the create element to hide it, but i am sure that there are other ways to fix this as well.

Here is an example with one existing element and one that will be created.

```js
var foo = document.getElementsByClassName("drag-me").item(0),
    bar = document.getElementsByClassName("drag-me").item(1);

// Drag foo and create custom element.
foo.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {

  var elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.id = "drag-ghost";
  elem.textNode = "Dragging";
  elem.style.position = "absolute";
  elem.style.top = "-1000px";
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(elem, 0, 0);

}, false);


// Drag bar and use foo as ghost image
bar.addEventListener("dragstart", function(e) {

  e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(foo, 0, 0);

}, false);


// Let's remove the created ghost elem on dragend
document.addEventListener("dragend", function(e) {

  var ghost = document.getElementById("drag-ghost");
  if (ghost.parentNode) {
    ghost.parentNode.removeChild(ghost);
  }

}, false);
```

```css
.drag-me {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 30px 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}

.drag-me:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.drag-me:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}

#drag-ghost {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="drag-me" draggable="true">Drag Me Foo</div>

<div class="drag-me" draggable="true">Drag Me Bar</div>
```

Comment: This will not work in IE as it does not support `setDragImage`. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20585673/5982321) for a work around for IE