# Microsoft Edge (And IE) Drag Event (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, microsoft-edge

I have a drag event working properly in Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Opera but when running in microsoft edge and IE i get the following error:

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'setDragImage'

Here is my code

```
function sDrag(e){
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', e.target.getAttribute("value"));
            var sample = e.target.getAttribute("sample");
            var imgTemp = document.createElement("img");
            imgTemp.src = "image.png";
            e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(imgTemp, 0, 0);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

`.setDragImage()` is not supported in IE11 and only partially in Edge.

You might have issues with `.setData()` and `.getData()` in IE11 as well.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop

Comment: Hi Shilly, could you point out what you mean by supported partially in Edge. I tried setting the drag image on edge but I get the same error that the method is not supported.

Comment: I meant that the setDragImage method of the DataTransfer API doesn't work at all in microsoft browsers. If you need it to work you can either code similar visuals yourself with some css. Or you could use a polyfill like https://github.com/MihaiValentin/setDragImage-IE/blob/master/setdragimage-ie.js or a similar jquery extension like shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766103/html5-drag-and-drop-events-and-setdragimage-browser-support